# Periodically polling a REST endpoint in Go

Tags: rest, go

I am trying to write a Go application that periodically polls a REST endpoint exposed by a PHP application. The Go polling application reads the payload into a struct and does further processing. I am looking for some recommendations for starting the implementation.

Comment: You may simply write a for loop which sleeps for sometime and poll the REST endpoint in every iteration. May be u will run the for loop in a dedicated goroutine. Else you may use Ticker (https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Ticker) also.

Comment: Thanks. Could this be implemented with long polling?

Comment: yes, can be used for long polling.

Comment: Sure it could be implemented with long polling if endpoint support this. You just don't Close connection but read chunks of data from http.Response.Body as them are available.

Answer (score 12):

Simplest way would be to use a Ticker:

```
ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 1).C
go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case <- ticker:
            response,_ := http.Get("http://...")
            _, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, response.Body)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            response.Body.Close()
        }
    }

}()


time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
```