# How to poll GitHub repo to pull on changes

Tags: go, github, go-git

I need to add this functionality into my GO program, with goal to poll the repo and perform a git pull on changes. I have been using https://github.com/src-d/go-git but am unable to find a way to poll.

I don't want to use a webhook to avoid creating a server for incoming payloads.

Comment: Git doesn't have that functionality. You'll have to set it up yourself, manually, and poll on a periodic basis.

Answer (score 0):

[go-git](https://github.com/src-d/go-git) does not provide this functionality out of the box, so you would need to write a small funciton.

1. In order to pull a repository periodically in Golang, one could use `time.Ticker`, as described in [Periodically polling a REST endpoint in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39363794/periodically-polling-a-rest-endpoint-in-go)
2. To pull from a Git repository, instead of `http.Get` for the REST API endpoint, one could use this [_examples/pull/main.go](https://github.com/src-d/go-git/blob/master/_examples/pull/main.go) from official go-git documentation

Let me know if that helps!